# Chametz owned by a Jew on 8th day of Pesach -- status after Pesach?

Tags: passover

Lets take the example of chametz gamur bought on the the 8th day chas veshalom -- **does the fact that the 8th day is rabbinic cancel out the prohibition of eating chametz, after passover, that was owned on passover?**

Comment: As I recall the reference to the secon day of yom tov is treated completely like the first day. As a result, a Jew in Chutz La'aretz would have to discard the chometz just as he would chametz owned on any other day of Pesach. I do not recall the source so I cannot make this an answer.

Comment: Doesn’t buying it on Yom Tov make it assur be’achila either way?

Comment: So you’re asking if it’s just the rabbinical issur or if it is a rabbinical and biblical issur?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/שולחן_ערוך_אורח_חיים_תסז_י

Comment: @bluejay there is no biblical prohibition of Baal Yaavor. The entire institution of חמץ שעבר עליו הפסח is rabbinic law.

Comment: @DoubleAA In that case the question becomes: Did the rabbis extend their prohibition to apply even to chametz owned on the 8th dayH?